# Is reduction of `constexpr` object lifetime legal in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, explicit-destructor-call

For ordinary objects (even for `const` ones), it is permissible to end their lifetime by explicitly calling the destructor. Later, for example, the program can start another object lifetime in the same memory location using placement `new`.

But is it legal to call the destructor of a `constexpr` object? Can it result in some useful or at least well-formed program?

It is easy to imagine the opposite situation:

```
struct A{
    int v = 0;
    constexpr void foo() { v ? throw 1 : ++v; }
    constexpr ~A() { foo(); }
};

constexpr A y;

int main() { y.~A(); y.~A(); }
```

This (most probably ill-formed) program is accepted by all compilers without any single warning: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aqMbfjxKT

And in Clang it finished by throwing an exception from `constexpr` destructor of `A`.

Comment: As far as I understood things constexpr is used to evaluate things at compile time.
But that if you make instances at runtime they behave like normal code.

In this case I think your real issue is that you are calling the destructor twice.
At least for me compiler explorer won't throw for clang if you remove that second destructor.

Comment: Interesting question. But, if the program **is** ill-formed (and I don't really know if it is or not), then I guess it is a little irrelevant to discuss how the compiled code behaves at runtime.

Comment: Evaluating code in constexpr context allows to detect UB; for clang: *"destruction of object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression"* [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sb6MGb7WE)..

Comment: You just step into https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#19.sentence-1 in your code, `constexpr` is irrelevant here. You prolly wanted to ask what happens if you call destructor in a constant evaluation context?

Comment: "_the program can start another object lifetime in the same memory location using placement `new`._" - How? `new (&y) A;` won't be valid since `&y` is a `const A*` and without placing a new `A` in the memory there will be a call to the destructor of an object after its lifetime. You'd have to cast away the `const` to be able to use placement new and then you have UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [[dcl.constexpr](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.constexpr-10)] A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const.

You can do with such an object whatever you can do with any other const object. `constexpr`, apart from implying constness of the declared object, doesn't seem to affect anything about the object itself. It only affects static properties of the program, that is, which expressions are constant expressions, which template instantiations are valid, etc. There are no special provisions for run-time behaviour of objects declared with the `constexpr` specifier.

The Standard uses phrases similar to "constexpr object" a couple of times but it seems to be a misnomer. In my opinion it should have referred to constexpr variables instead. There should be no such thing as "constexpr objects" (like there are no inline objects), only constexpr variables (like there are inline variables). After all, `constexpr` is a decl-specifier, like `inline`. The objects that these variables refer to are just const.